# regarding placing the txt file for java to read it right away

Tags: java

I want to read text and STORE it in a String variable ...
   This code is working fine but i want to know where the txt file should be placed exactly for me to not  specify the exact path. Since I'll be trying this code on various machines . so I hope you understood what I want.

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.util.*;
    public class Compress {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
            String text="";
            try {
                text = new Scanner( new File("C:\\Users\\sandhya\\workspace\\PrefixFreeCodeChecker\\src\\poem.txt"), "UTF-8" ).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(text+"");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Place the file in the directory where your java-app is run from and use a relative path for the filename, like `new File("poem.txt")`

Comment: Definitely, relative paths are the best you can do. And avoid any hint of the Microsoftish drive-leter syntax, since that will not work on other platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Put your poem.txt file in your java project folder and change the path to this:

```
text = new Scanner( new File("poem.txt").....
```

Comment: Thanks ! it worked ... btw my output is giving me a "?" character at the first position in the output String

Comment: It's probably a problem with your text file. Did it have a "?" before?

Comment: Thanks user3286112! Seems like the character "?" was appearing when the txt file was saved in UTF-8 encoding. But it went fine when I changed the encode type to ANSI :)